# Why does diazo coupling preferentially occur at the para position?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

When the diazonium ion couples with dimethylaniline, why is the para position favored?
[image]

Is this only due to steric factors or do electronic factors (such as ortho-para directivity) play a role here too? In particular, I suspect ortho-para electronic factors might be significant because some of the resonance structures have a cation directly next to the electron-donating group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both steric and electronic factors play a role in this reaction.  Resonance structures such as those shown below favor electrophilic attack (the diazonium ion is an electrophile) at the *ortho* and *para* positions. Since there are twice as many *ortho* positions as *para* positions in N,N-dimethylaniline, on a purely statistical basis we might expect a 67:33 *ortho/para* product distribution if only electronic effects controlled the reaction.  Since diazonium coupling usually produces a majority of the *para* coupled product, steric factors must be playing a role as well.  The somewhat bulky dimethylamino group does make it more difficult for an electrophile to approach the *ortho* position and the diazonium ion is relatively large.  These two steric factors combine to reduce the amount of the *ortho* isomer and the *para* isomer predominates.

[image]